# is it possible can default sort in datagrid with itemRender label?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, datagrid, itemrenderer

We know already Datagrid default sorting,  when we click on header of dategrid then automatically sorting records well. But how can we sort within inline itemreander linkfield label in datagrid. In project default sorting properly work in datagrid but linked field column only not sorting?
Is it any way to sort functionality? if u know please refer it.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your questions 100% but thought I'd let you know that I had a similar question answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12625958/487812

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a `sortCompareFunction` for the column using the inline item renderer.

[Check the FLEX API Reference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/dataGridClasses/DataGridColumn.html#sortCompareFunction)